# Get the text of clicked .filter

Tags: jquery

If I click the first link, I want to display/alert `Cat100`. If the second link is clicked, then `Cat200`.

How can I reach this content? I can't find a solution. Many thanks for help.

```js
$(".filter").click(function() {
  alert("Value: " + $("a.div").text); // doesn't work!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <a href="">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat100</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  <a href="">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat200</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: alert($(this).find('.title').html())

Comment: alert("Value: " + $("a.div",$(this)).first().html());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should prevent the default action of the event (link is clicked), so your page does not change. Than I expect you want the title e.g. **Cat100**, but your listener is on `.filter`, so you need to find the `div` with the class `title` and get the `text()` from it:

```js
$(".filter").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Value: " + $(this).find('div.title').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat100</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat200</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the `text()` from each individual `.title` element then you need to change your selector to target them directly, which you can do using `find()`.

In addition you need to use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked element, and add `()` after `.text` to actually invoke the function. Finally you'll need to call `preventDefault()` on the raised `click` event to stop the parent `<a>` element from unloading the page and causing a redirect. Try this:

```js
$(".filter").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Value: " + $(this).find('.title').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <a href="">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat100</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  <a href="">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat200</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by targeting the .`title` div.

Here's a runnable snippet to demonstrate:

```js
$(".filter").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // to prevent the link from move to another page.
  // for UX on the site, I changed the alert() by console.log(), just for this demo. You can change it back to alert if you want.
  console.log('Value: ' + $(this).find('.title').text()); 

});
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <a href="">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat100</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  <a href="">
    <div class="type">Filter</div>
    <div class="title">Cat200</div>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```